# what is wrong with the __call__ method

Tags: python

```
class Time:
    def __init__(self,hour=0, minute= 0, second=0):
        if type(hour) != int or type(minute) != int or type(second) != int or hour < 0 or hour > 23 or minute < 0 or minute > 59 or second < 0 or second > 59:
            raise AssertionError
        self.hour = hour
        self.minute = minute 
        self.second = second
        self._date = datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1, hour, minute, second)

    def __call__(self):
        return Time(self.hour,self.minute,self.second)
```

I am writing the Time class, and I wrote the **init** method and the **call** method. The **call** method allow an object from this class to be callable with three int arguments: update the hour of the object to be the first argument, and the minute of the object to be the second argument, and the second of the object to be the third argument. it should return None, if any parameter is not legal and raise an AssertionError with an appropriate string describing the problem/values.

my **call** method does not work, can someone tell me how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

test call

```
c-->t = Time()
c-->t(16,2,5)
e-->t-->4:02:05pm
c-->t(4,23,16)
e-->t-->4:23:16am
^-->t(5,60,12)-->AssertionError
```

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work? Do you get some error? Please mention the stack-trace

Comment: What are you trying to do here? There wasn't any exception raised when I ran the code

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri: I imagine part of OP's problem is that they mention the `__call__` method taking three arguments, but in their code it only takes one.  Beyond that, we can't really diagnose without more information.

Comment: yes that's the error I got

Comment: I do not know how to fix it

Comment: Please show how you used your method.

Comment: I add the test function.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the call. It is just that 60 minutes == 1 hour. You can't give 60 as an argument for minutes or seconds, only 0-59.